# Boundary conditions for streamlines in enclosed flow

Tags: finite-element, numerical-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to solve Lid driven square cavity flow problem of Stokes equation using finite element method. I have boundary conditions for velocity as zeros on every boundary but u=1 on top boundary. can you please help me with the boundary conditions of stream function and how to obtain ? especially on top boundary.

I have gone through many literature but why most of them considered as zero on every boundary.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity and stream function are related by
$$
u = \psi_y, \qquad v = - \psi_x
$$
This can be related to the vorticity
$$
-\Delta \psi = \omega = v_y - u_x
$$
On left and right, we have $(u,v)=(0,0)$
$$
\psi = const, \quad \psi_x = 0
$$
On bottom $(u,v) = (0,0)$
$$
\psi_y = 0, \qquad \psi = const
$$
On top $(u,v)=(u_0,0)$
$$
\psi_y = u_0, \qquad \psi = const
$$
You cannot enforce two boundary conditions. Let us use Dirichlet bc
$$
\psi = const
$$
on all boundaries. Since $\psi$ must be continuous (assuming $\omega$ in $L^2$ atleast), the constant must be same on all sides which you can set to zero.

Comment: I had some doubt that psi_y =u0 does not mean psi = constant, it can be psi=u0y

Comment: On top boundary $\psi = const$ implies $\psi$ does not depend on $x$. $y$ is already fixed on the top boundary.. The other condition says $\psi_y(x,y_{top}) = u_0$ but you cannot integrate this as you seem to do, because that condition holds only at $y=y_{top}$. The thing is you have two bc on the top, a dirichlet and neumann. I am suggesting to use dirichlet bc. The solution you get must satisfy the other bc, maybe only in a weak sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the streamline formulation the divergence equation for the velocity $\vec{v}=(u,v)^{T}$ 
$$\mathrm{div}\,\vec{v}=0$$
holds identically if 
$$ \vec{v} =(u,v)^{T}= \left( \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial y},-\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}\right)^{T}\tag{*}$$

For boundaries in which the velocity is $\vec{v}=\vec{0}$, it is easy to see from $(*)$ that $\Psi=constant$ and $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{\mathrm{grad}}\,\Psi=0$. Without any loss of generality you can set this constant to $0$.

On the other hand, on the top of the cavity in which $\vec{v}=(u_0,0)^{T}$ the streamline function $\Psi$ must fulfill:
$$ \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial y}=v_0\qquad \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}=0 $$